# Rails serialize symbols array attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, serialization

I have an array field in one of my models, with elements being symbols. For example, here is how I assign values to this field:

```
Model.field = [:a, :b, :c]
```

I use Postgres so I store these arrays in an array column. The problem is that Rails automatically serializes the symbols from the given array to strings when saving them to the database, but doesn't convert them back to symbols when objects are fetched from the database. How can I tell my model to automatically convert array values to symbols?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I'll delete my answer as you need an "automatic" way of doing it.

Comment: Indeed. I am thinking about using `serialize :field, Serializer`, but I guess that `Serializer` already exists for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could try overriding the attribute reader method and doing the datatype conversion there

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def field
    self[:field].map(&:to_sym)
  end
end
```

Comment: I prefer not to, since I will have a hard time dealing with other ActiveRecord goodies (such as `attributes`).